# How to implement colspan within table

Tags: html, css

I'm new to this site, so I will try and explain my situation as clearly as I can!

I am currently trying to create a HTML form with 4 input fields and one textarea contained within a table.

I am trying to set my textarea to cover 2 rows within the table so I've used the `colspan` tag. Though this doesn't seem to be working (see picture) and when I change the textarea height within my CSS file, the input fields are being pushed further over to the right and I'm unsure why.

My HTML code for the form:

```
<table style='width:100%'>
   <tr>
      <th><input type='text' name='name' required placeholder='Name' />
      <th> 
      <th><input type='text' name='email' required placeholder='Email' /></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th><input type='text' name='mobile' required placeholder='Mobile'/>
      <th> 
      <th><input type='text' name='subject' required placeholder='subject' /></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th colspan='2'> <textarea></textarea></th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

My actual outcome: 
[See Screenshot](https://dyp.im/ZqgDCuPUHH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have accidentally created a new table head cell (`<th>` on line 4) instead of closing the first (`</th>`).

This should hilight the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/odvnLy52/1/

With your HTML the browser will create a table with 3 columns, not 2. The last cell will span 2 of those 3 columns.

This is an example with the HTML fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/odvnLy52/